# Java version of Python's def function

Tags: java, python, function

While I am most fluent in Python, I've recently started learning Java. I was wondering if there is a similar function in Java to Python's def function. Something that allows me to write some code and store it within a callable function is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

No, java Dosen't have any def keyword for declaring functions, instead it has declaring methods inside classes like:

```
public static void myMethod(string[] args){
```